# Why is Icon List not appearing in Xcode?

Tags: ios, applications, xcode

I am trying to add an icon into my iPhone application. To do this, I need to add an icon image via the Xcode interface into my plist option labeled "Icon List."

However, the "Icon List" option under my plist options is not appearing. Is Xcode hiding it somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real key name you're looking for is `CFBundleIconFiles`. Xcode displays short human-readable names for several keys; this one should be called "Icon files", but you can enter the key directly.

See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480563/how-do-i-specify-both-icons-for-a-universal-iphone-ipad-app) for more discussion.